# Page size dropdownlist and CListView not working in yii

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, yii, yii-extensions, page-size

I am traying to make a dropdown pagination in my project, but it's not working correctly.
Whatever the number that I select in the dropdownlist, it still shows 10 items in the page.
What I am missing ?

Thank you.

[Screenshot](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=666285Untitled.jpg)

The view code :

```
 <?php
    //$dataProvider->pagination->pageSize = 25;

    $pageSize=Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']); 
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('pageSize',$pageSize,array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20,25=>25,30=>30),
    array('onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiGridView.update('packages-grid',{ data:{pageSize: $(this).val() }})",
    'empty'=>'-- Select Page Range --','style'=>'width:198px;'));

    $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
        'id'=>'propertylistview',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'summaryText'=>'',
        'itemView'=>'_propertyview',
            'sortableAttributes' => array(
                .........
             )
     ));
    ?>
```

The controller code :

```
public function actionAdmin(){         
if (isset($_GET['pageSize'])) {
 Yii::app()->user->setState('pageSize',(int)$_GET['pageSize']);
 unset($_GET['pageSize']);}
    $model=new Packages('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes(); 
    if(isset($_GET['Packages']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Packages'];       
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Packages'); 
    $this->render('admin',array('model'=>$model,'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

I already added this to model search

```
return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this),array(
            'pagination'=>array(
                'pageSize'=> Yii::app()->user->getState('pageSize',Yii::app()->params['defaultPageSize']),
            ),
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
```

and this to config/main.php

```
'params'=>array('defaultPageSize'=> '10'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing an ajax call but in your widget you do not state any update part to update. `ajaxUpdate` is the solution.

And you are using `'onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiGridView.update` while using a CListView so change the js to `'onchange'=>"$.fn.yiiListView.update` and:

```
<?php
// your code    
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
   'id'=>'propertylistview',
   'ajaxUpdate' => 'propertylistview', //add this line
   'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
   'summaryText'=>'',
   'itemView'=>'_propertyview',
   'sortableAttributes' => array(
   //etc.. )
));
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. But it's still the same thing allyaws shows 10 items even if I select 15 20 etc..